# Is a thin power strip a safety hazard?

Tags: safety, mains

I have a US-style power strip that is thin enough that plugs can overhang the edge. It is easy to do this accidentally.

I think that if you were to overhang a plug, and then accidentally touch the plug with one hand and a grounded object like the radiator pipe with the other, you would be creating a circuit like:

[image]

The safety page on my oscilloscope manual warns that 30 V AC (rms) can cause a fatal 30 mA AC (rms) current through a human body, so presumably the 120 V AC wall power can drive 120 mA AC; at which point the average resistance of the human would be 1 kOhm. If the appliance were a 60 W light bulb, it would be 240 Ohms, reducing the current to 97 mA AC, still fatal.

So, my best guess is that this power strip is unsafe. Is this correct?

Comment: So are you essentially asking "Is touching live mains electricity unsafe"?

Comment: Converting humans and appliances into pure resistances is not a precise model to estimate the current that would go through a person and therefore its potential fatality.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you mean by "plugs can overhang the edge". Perhaps you could add a photo to better illustrate this.

Comment: @Owen I think that what you mean is that you can plug just 1 pin of the plug into the socket, the other pin is free. Is that right?

Comment: @SteveG Yes, that is what I wanted to say. Thank you.

Comment: If you are unlucky to plug the 1 pin into the live socket then the free pin will be connected to live through the appliance. It is very unlikely that the appliance will limit the current to a safe level (and your own calculations are wrong). I would class that as potentially unsafe.